# Using Spring Boot Actuator endpoints with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am very new to the Play Framework and a project I am working on has several applications of various flavors: Akka both java and scala, Spring java, and Play. We want to standardize the health endpoints across all and have a good deal of experience with spring boot actuator endpoints -- used it across all Spring-based java applications in another project.

My question is, does it make sense to consider standardizing our approach by using spring boot actuator integration even with our Play applications and has anyone out there ever attempted this.